# Pointers in C and C++ used with prefix operator '++'

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to understand pointers in C and was trying a code sample, which gave an absurd result.

Following is the code sample :

```
void main()
{
    int *a;
    int arr[5] = {1,3,4,5,2};
    printf("%d\n", *(arr+1));
    a = arr;
    printf("Address: %p || Value: %d\n", ++a, *a);
}
```

okay so I expected it to output the `address` and `value` of second index of the array but unfortunately the output `value` isn't not equal to 3 (the second index value of the array) as opposed to the address which comes out correct.

The problem here is that the prefix `++a` expression doesn't update the pointer variable `a` and when later in the printf function `a` is `dereferenced` the updated value is not used and hence the output shows the first index value of the array.

Please help me on this.

Comment: This absurd behavior is caused by undefined behavior of your program.

Comment: There are many things a Java programmer needs to unlearn when learning C or C++. That function arguments are evaluated in a particular order is one of them.

Comment: @molbdnilo In C, the function arguments are not evaluated in a specified order.

Comment: @chux function arguments aren't evaluated in a particular order, but that is fundamental right? or not?

Comment: @haccks okay let me understand it the right way, here the absurd behaviour is caused by the arguments not evaluating in a specified order, right?

Comment: @mohitR0_0; Yes. you got it right.

Comment: @haccks okay but the post you referred talks about the constructs related to only unary '++' and not function arguments undefined behaviour, won't it be fine to just not tag it as duplicate since it's not the same.

Comment: it us because the `*a` is passed earlier than the `++a` and it is implementation defined.

Comment: @chux Exactly. Hence, it is something that you need to unlearn.

Comment: @P__J__ is it correct to say that in this particular implementation the arguments to a function is always passed in a right to left order?

Comment: You cant relay on it. Just move operations outside the function call.

Comment: yes that should be the correct practice I guess

Comment: @mohitR0_0: The problem goes beyond evaluation order - attempting to modify the value of an object  (`++a`)  and then use that value of that object in a computation (`*a`) without an intervening sequence point is explicitly called out as *undefined behavior* by the language definition, and the result of undefined behavior can be quite literally anything.  It's a coding error, period, regardless of how the compiler orders the operations.